# Python dictionary multiple values per key iterating with jinja2

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, jinja2

I have a dictionary (created from a Pandas dataframe):

```
{'name': 'steve', 'info': [{'pipeline': 'product1, product2'}]}
```

and this is the jinja2 sintax in a .docx template:

```
{% for x in info %} 
•   {{x[‘pipeline’]}}
{%endfor%}
```

the output is:

•   product1, product2

**but I'd like to have:**

•   product1

•   product2

I'm not able to iterate and separate the values of the "info" key.

Comment: you need to register a custom filter. I do not know which module do you use. but, [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) can give you an idea. i.e. `{{ x[‘pipeline’] | your_custom_tag }}`... . `def your_custom_tag(arg): return "\n".join(arg.split(", "))`

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as the value of pipeline is a string you need to add info.split(',') to get [product1, product] as a list that you can iterate over